# Windows Batch files and SQLite

Tags: windows, sqlite, batch-file

When creating a batch file in Windows for SQLite, can the batch file run any commands after it has entered the SQLite shell?  Or is it only possible to add command line options?

What I want to do is create a batch file that that starts SQLite and loads the database I want.  Then it runs several SQLite commands and then quits.

Comment: Try the solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585849/may-i-run-a-script-on-sqlite-command-line)

Comment: I am using Windows.  That seems to be a BASH solution, right?

Comment: what about putting all commands into text file and directing stream into sqlite: ```sqlite3 database.db < commands.sql```

Comment: I didnt know that was possible.  I will mess around with the syntax you have provided but let me know if you have somekind of link with some examples of using this method.  I don't know a lot about batch files. :(

Comment: Nevermind. It seems in the end, the simplest way to do this was to use an AutoHotKey script to emulate a user actually typing in the commands I wanted into the cmd line. I guess sometimes the answer is to use another tool.